# Add record to MySQL using AJAX / jquery on multiple elements with the same class

Tags: php, jquery

Im new here and I have some difficulties to make my code to work. Hope u guys can help me. Im displaying records form MySQL in a modal box in a table format. Each row has its own add (+) button generated via php loop which displays records that should be leter on, added to a different table using jquery on click event and AJAX. Each td row is provided with an input field with class name "idKont", but only the first one will be added after I click on the + / add button.

```
$('#add_kontpers').on("click", function(e) {

 e.preventDefault();


var ptId = $('#idAj').text();   // ID of the customer that will be passed
var idKont = $('.idKont').val(); // ID of the contact person 

$.ajax ({

      url: "folder/insert_data.php",
      method:"POST",
      data: 
          {
              id: ptId,
              idKont: idKont
          },

      dataType:'text',
      success: function(result) {
                //$('#myModal').modal('hide'); 
                $('#alert_modal').append( '<div class="alert alert-success">Success</div>' ).fadeIn(1000).fadeOut(4000);
            }

      })

})
```

and this is the HTML Code with PHP:

```
                          <!-- Modal content-->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header" style="padding:10px 50px;">
      <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span> Choose Contact Person</p>
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body" style="padding: 40px 50px;">
      <form role="form" method="post">

            <div id="alert_modal"></div>

                <table class="table table-responsive">
                  <thead class="thead-light">
                    <tr>
                      <th>ID</th>
                      <th>Vorname</th>
                      <th>Name</th>
                      <th>Tel</th>
                      <th>Mobil</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody> 

                    <?php

                        try {

                        $stmt = $connser->prepare("SELECT ID, Vorname, Name, Tel, Mobil FROM Contactperson ORDER BY ID DESC");

                        $stmt->execute();

                                           while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {

                                               $kontID = $row['ID']; 

                    ?>                                 

                                                    <tr>
                                                    <td><?php echo $row['ID']; ?></td>
                                                    <td><?php echo $row['Vorname']; ?></td>
                                                    <td><?php echo $row['Name']; ?></td> 
                                                    <td><?php echo $row['Tel']; ?></td>
                                                    <td><?php echo $row['Mobil']; ?></td>
                                                    <td><input class="idKont" value="<?php echo $kontID; ?>" type="hidden"  /></td>
                                                    <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-success add_kontpers">+</button></td>
                                                    </tr>


                    <?php    
                                           }
                        }

                        catch(PDOException $e) {

                            echo "Error";
                            //echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
                            exit;

                        }

                    ?>

                  </tbody>
              </table>

      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-default pull-left" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

The modal box stays open and it shoud be, but if I click the first element on the top, then only this one will be added. I would like to have the oportunity to click for example one position on the list to add it to the table, the the second one, and so on, but if I click other butten then the first one then the modalbox will be closed and the website reloads. Any help or pinting in the right direction will be highly appreciated.

Comment: How is your html looking like?

Comment: Hi Ntiyiso Rikhotso, I added the whol Modal Box HTML with PHP

Answer (score 1):

Two things, first you can't reuse the same ID and by having `add_kontpers` in a loop, you will reusing that.

So first, change that to a class and `idAj` doesn't exist in the provided code.

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success add_kontpers">
```

Then make this change in your jQUERY

```
$('.add_kontpers').on("click", function(e) {

 e.preventDefault();

var ptId = $('#idAj').text();   ?????????????????????
var idKont = $(this).parents("tr").find('.idKont').val(); // ID of the contact person
```

Comment: Hi imvain2, thank you for your help. The ptId is getting a value from span. It is an ID form another table in order to be able later on to assign it to the idKont in anothe table. After that through inner join Im able to display the desired results and it is working. The value of the var idKont will be displayed and shows if I console.log it. And it is also working because the first row after clicking on the add button is being added to the database. I only cant do it with jquery and ajax :(. Ive tried your solution, but it doesnt work. After clicking on the second element the modalbox closes.

Comment: Hi imvain2, your answer helped me a lot. Only evt.stopPropagation(); and evt.stopImmediatePropagation(); were missing. And everything is working as excpected. Thank you very much for your help ;).

Answer (score 0):

Javascript

```
$(document)
   .on('click', 'button#add_kontpers', function(a){
     a.preventDefault();
     var button = $(this);
     var row    = button.closest('tr');
     var id     = row.find('input').val();

     $.post("folder/insert_data.php", {id : id, idKont : id})
      .done(function(response){
        //Your response
       })

   })
```